# SharePoint REST API. 400 Bad Request when Making an AJAX call on SharePoint List

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint

Good Afternoon.
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I have a REST API call on a SharePoint list and for the life of me cannot figure out why I'm getting a 400 Bad Request message. Here's my call....

```
myURL = "my sharepoint site URL"

$.ajax({
url: myURL + "/org/Analysis/_api/web/list/GetByTitle('Analysis')/items?$filter=Accepted%20eq%20%27Yes%27&$select=Date_x0020_of_x0020_Activity, Accepted"
method: "GET"
headers:{"ACCEPT" : "application/json;odata=verbose",
"content-type":"application/json;odata=verbose"
},
// success function and some other stuff


});
```

Thank you in advance....

Comment: What is the value of `myURL` ?  What does your REST API call look like?  Please edit your question and add in these details.

Comment: sorry, can't put a URL in my post.

Comment: Have you verified that the value of `url` works when you copy/paste that value into your browser?  Also, have you verified the details of the request on the Network tab of F12 dev tools in your browser?

Comment: Also, have you tried simplifying your url by removing the filter? (just to test to see if that is the problem)

Comment: And, there seem to be several similar questions on https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/ .  You might find more specific help there.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with changing the code?

```
headers: { 
    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
    "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following url

```
_api/web/list/GetByTitle('Analysis')/items?$select=Date_x0020_of_x0020_Activity,Accepted&$filter=Accepted eq 'Yes'
```